# I get an error 'Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [q]'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I use elasticsearch for the drop-down list of cities when searching.

```
Error: Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [q]
```

I checked all the parameters that are passed, everything should be correct

Location controller:
https://pastebin.com/CMEEXSU3

City model:
https://pastebin.com/XWWNTDFD

JS:
https://pastebin.com/kEDes10b

Error:
https://pastebin.com/k48yPmKD

Comment: It sees the `City model` link is not the correct one (same as the `JS` one)

Comment: @Val Oh, I didn't notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still, the wrong parameters came to me.

Corrected so:

*Location controller:*

```
def fetch_locations
    locations = []
    p params[:q]
    search = CountryCity.search(params[:q])

    search.each do |result|
      locations << result.city + ', ' + result.name
    end

    render json: {locations: locations}
end
```

*City model:*

```
def self.search params
    CountryCity.__elasticsearch__.search(params)
end
```